# Parent and Child Components Structure (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, components, structure

I have multiple components already created that are on the same level which makes it hard for me to pass data between them.
The HealthForm component has an input field which takes a host url and then fetches to APIs when a button is click. All of that works well.
What I need is to pass that url to all the other components (ProductForm, xForm, yForm, zForm...) What I have now is that my backend server saves the url but that creates implications whee multiple browsers are using the webpage.

What I'm thinking that needs to be changed is to make the HealthForm the parent component of the other Forms.
However, my App.js looks like this which has only the routes in it. A separate HeaderTabs links to the right routes...

**EDIT**
The code now successfully saves and passes the url to its child components. The issue is that the page re-renders when i update the parent state in HealthForm.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            url: '',

        };
        this.setURL = this.setURL.bind(this);
  }

  setURL(page) {
        this.setState({
            url: page
        });
        console.log("Parent url: " + this.state.url);
  }

 render(){
  return(
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router>
            <div className="App">

                <Route path="/" component={()=>(
                    <div>
                        <Header/>
                        <HealthForm changeUrl={this.setURL} urlProp={this.state.url}/>)}>/>
                    </div>)}/>

                <Route path="/path1" component={ProductForm}></Route>
                <Route path="/path2" component={xForm}></Route>
                <Route path="/path3" component={yForm}></Route>
                <Route path="/path4" component={zForm}></Route>

            </div>
        </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
 }
}
```

HealthForm

```
class HealthForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        exampleURL: '',
        exampleURLError: '',
        status: '',
        showStatus: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 validate = () => {
 //…checks for input errors
           }
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextProps !== nextState;
    }

 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const err = this.validate();
    let that = this;
    if (!err) {
                       this.setState({
            exampleURLError: ''
        });
        console.log(this.state);
        var data = this.state.exampleURL

         fetch('http://somehost/health', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    var promiseStatus = res.text();
                    promiseStatus.then(function (value) {
                        console.log("StatusHA: " + value);
                        that.setState({
                            status: value,
                            showStatus: true
                        });

                        if (that.shouldComponentUpdate(that.state.jarvisURL, that.props.urlProp)) 
                            that.props.changeUrl(that.state.jarvisURL);
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
    }
 }

 render() {
        return (
            <form>  
            <TextField
              ...
            />
            <br/>

             <Button variant="contained" size="small" color="primary" onClick={e => this.handleSubmit(e)} >
                Check
            </Button>
            <br />  <br /> 

              ...

            </form>  
        );
 }


}
export default HealthForm;
```

All other forms are pretty similar to HealthForm.

How can i reorganize my code to make HealthForm the parent component? Or is making a brand new parent component with all the forms being its children a better option? If so, any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I made the changes Snaz suggested which sucessfully sends the url to App's state but now

```
 this.props.changeUrl(url);
```

causes the whole app to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass a function to HealthForm, that will change property of App's state and by changing state it will refresh and send this to other forms? Something like this:

App:

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    url: ''
}

foobar(page){
    this.setState({
        url: page
    });
}

 render(){
  return(
[code here...]
                    <HealthForm changeUrl={this.foobar}/>
[code there...]
  );
 }
}
```

And in HealthForm in handleSubmit you just call:

```
this.props.changeUrl(url);
```

This should give the page to App and then you can pass this url to other forms in similar way showed here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105

Comment: That's exactly what I have been trying out but couldn't get it quite right. Much appreciated. The only thing i changed from your suggestion is that I made a constructor for App.
Now i get this error:
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: The problem that's causing the warning is that i have HealthForm setState in my fetch call that gets the values of the promise returned. Looking at that right now

Comment: I moved this.props.changeUrl(url); to be part of the fetch call and it fixed the warning. The page is still refreshing though

Comment: If your page is refreshing in loop, use shouldComponentUpdate and check if nextState-> url is different than current url in state, if so, then return true, otherwise return false. This should make to render only if page url changed.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: with shouldComponentUpdate it re-renders only when the url changes as you said, but I need it to not do that regardless if  the url state is changed. Is that possible? I have some user info that needs to be displayed after i do the health api call and that is never showed bc of the re-render resets the page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Your page loads entirely, in some case (for example some event, like button click) there is api call, for some reason page refreshes and nothing happend with api response? if so, save api response to state, re-rendering doesn't flush state. Otherwise, please provide more information or even some code example.

Comment: Sorry about that, the page does load entirely, then i can enter the url, the button performs the api call, i get the response as intended, and more information is technically displayed as intended again. However the page re-renders immediately since the state in App.js is changed so the user is unable to see the changes on the page. I included the api call in my original post.

Comment: First, in shouldComponentUpdate method, nextProps is totally different thing than state of component. Component is able to have some default props, but usually they are delivered by parent's component, please look here and analyze this simple demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/115294/
In Parent's component in render in <Child /> try to delete for a while data={} and you'll se defaultProps.
Another thing, I believe, that you shouldn't call shouldComponentUpdate by yourself, it's in component's lifecycle and if you change state, this method will be called automatically.

Comment: Again, I think you should save your api response in state, then in case of refresh of the page you won't lost your data and it will be still displayed.